# How would the Israelites have girded their loins?

Tags: ancient-history, middle-east, clothing

I stumbled upon the [Art of Manliness guide to girding their loins](https://www.artofmanliness.com/articles/how-to-gird-up-your-loins-an-illustrated-guide/) earlier. However, their source is a Historyzine article which doesn't have any references. Also, on Youtube, you can find an alternative explanation in which the backside of the tunic is instead tied into a belt (like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDucY-Ueb7A)).

So, do we have any primary or secondary sources describing how this would have been done in antiquity?

Comment: Here's an article with lots of relevant references: https://sci-hub.st/10.1177/0309089211419417

One of the key sources it points to is a close reading of the Book of Job: http://web.archive.org/web/20080301165842/http://www.shef.ac.uk/bibs/DJACcurrres/Loingirding.html